# Number of handshakes at a party

Tags: combinatorics

10 indian and 10 american couples meet at a party and shake hands. if no wife shakes hands with her husband and no indian wife shakes hands with a male, then the number of hand shakes that take place at the party is?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? How far did you get?

Comment: That's racism...

Answer (score 5):

1. Take the possible number of handshakes between $2$ out of $40$ people: $\binom{40}{2}$
2. Subtract the possible number of handshakes between a husband and his wife: $20$
3. Subtract the possible number of handshakes between an Indian wife and a male: $10\times20$
4. Add the possible number of handshakes between an Indian wife and her (male) husband: $10$

The result is $\binom{40}{2}-20-10\times20+10 = 780-20-200+10 = 570$

Please note that in step #$4$ you need to add the possible number of handshakes between an Indian wife and her (male) husband, because you subtract this number twice (in step #$2$ and in step #$3$).

Answer (score 4):

Male - male handshakes $= {20 \choose 2}$. Female - female handshakes $= {20 \choose 2}$. Indian female - male handshakes $=0$. American female - male handshakes $=19 \times 10$. Total handshakes $=570.$